Van won’t start, lights occasionally come on when key turned to ignition
I have a 2017 Ford transit connect, I was driving just fine one day then when coming up to the light the car engine died and it said transmission not in park. So i turned off the van and tried to start it in park but wouldn’t crank and the lights remained solid.  I tried to switch it to Neutral to push it into a parking lot but it was stuck in park and wouldn’t shift.
You’re truck driver came and unlocked the stick and got it to neutral for the tow, got it home and started testing fuses, starter, battery and a few other things.  Noticed only the driver side of the cars headlights and break lights are on someone’s when the lights come on.  Most of the time when the key is inserted and turned nothing will happen, no dash lights or anything but occasionally it’ll turn on the dash lights, noticed the radio will turn on regardless of key state or even if the key isn’t inserted in the car which isn’t normal i think.
We tried taping the starter solenoid and managed to get it to crank by bypassing the starter fuse, but have yet to get the key to do anything other than occasionally turn on the electronics inside the van and half the lights outside… thoughts?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds like you have more than one issue.

Indeed, not sure why it all fell apart today, but hopefully someone has some ideas.  And hopefully it ain’t a wire somewhere fried, i ain’t a mechanic and can’t afford a full diagnosis yet so hopefully ideas will point me in the right direction.

I would look at the ignition switch. It seems like it is the common "thing" which is tying problems together. I say this partly because you were able to get it started by bypassing it. It lights up everything "sometimes". It seems like the most logical thing, but I don't know how you could test it.

We did try a new ignition switch also last night so unless both of them are borked… the switch is the little box in the steering wheel column right?  If so yah we tried swapping that out and same result

Then you need to check everything going forward of that ... it has to be something in the ignition system causing it, such as a bad wire. At least that would be my working theory.

So after doing some Sleuthing with a mechanic friend from afar and some testing of the ignition switch, I get 0.01v from the hot wire in the switch, very odd since it should be 12v, or something, battery is reading a 12.89v I checked the pins on my fuse box just out of curiosity and noticed one of the pins in the fuse box is missing, aka link Very peculiar, might not be what's causing my issue but can't hurt to ask if anyone knows what that pin might go to.  Saw one selling online that had that pin, the one at the bottom isn't suppose to have a pin.
